# Visual Studio 2010 replaces the character under the cursor when typing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-cursor

I have been having this problem sometimes on Visual Studio 2010 (and Notepad++), where my text cursor, if I move it, turns into a "console" cursor, where that if you add characters it replaces the character you were on instead of adding the character in front of it.

I hope there is something that can be done about this.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing the "insert" key to toggle insert / overwrite mode would undo this

Answer (score 1):

Double click on OVR text located to the right bottom of visual studio 2010 or 2012 and it will change to INSERT and that should help.

[image: screen shot visual studio]